# Laravel 4 class not found after doployment to production

Tags: laravel, classloader

Error:

> Class 'App\Package\PackageServiceProvider' not found

After moving my laravel directories to my server. The app is under psr-0.

The same files are found and working locally without any errors.

I tried to update composer with and without dump but nothing changes.

Why does that happen?

Comment: Did you composer install on the production server?

Comment: Developing on windows and publishing to Unix environment by any chance?

Comment: I am using vagrant to develop my application. Also to deploy my amazon server.

Comment: @MattStauffer, thanks. I thought that it is enought to run once inside the project folder. I have to checkout composer process :) If you write it as an answer; i want to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the vendor directory is not checked into your git repository. So, just run `composer install` on your server and it should take care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks Hilmi Erdem KEREN! I'm happy it helped.